# Read HL7 message without prescribing message type or event type or version

Tags: java, hl7, hapi

I need to read an HL7, pipe-delimited message into a custom Java structure that represents the message structure. I need to do all this without using any message type, event type, or version specific methods or classes, because I need this code to work no matter what kind of HL7 message is read. I don't want to write a reader for every different message and event type. I need to get all the segments and subfields. I have looked at HAPI a lot to see if it has a prebuilt solution for this problem, but I have found nothing.

Is there anyway to extend a HAPI class or iterate over the underlying message structure that HAPI creates from a parser to solve this problem?

Also, any good resources on HAPI would be appreciated.

Comment: The underlying message structure is going to change based on the message type/event. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your project, but there's a good likelihood that you'll find very, very few projects that need to consume every message type/event possible. Just like with any type of software development, you need to identify what your program is going to do and what information it needs. This will identify what you actually need to consume.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to parse HL7 message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050402/need-to-parse-hl7-message)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [HL7X library for Java](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hl7x/). This library offers you to transform any HL7 to an XML. It does not depend on MessageType, EventType nor version (big difference to HAPI).

Example:

```
MSH|^~\&|||||20121116122025||ADT^A01|5730224|P|2.5||||||UNICODE UTF-8
EVN|A01|20130120151827
PID||0|123||Name^Firstname^^^^||193106170000|w
PV1||E|
```

Gets transformed to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HL7X>
<HL7X>
    <MSH>
        <MSH.1>^~\&amp;</MSH.1>
        <MSH.6>20121116122025</MSH.6>
        <MSH.8>
            <MSH.8.1>ADT</MSH.8.1>
            <MSH.8.2>A01</MSH.8.2>
        </MSH.8>
        <MSH.9>5730224</MSH.9>
        <MSH.10>P</MSH.10>
        <MSH.11>2.5</MSH.11>
        <MSH.17>UNICODE UTF-8</MSH.17>
    </MSH>
    <EVN>
        <EVN.1>A01</EVN.1>
        <EVN.2>20130120151827</EVN.2>
    </EVN>
    <PID>
        <PID.2>0</PID.2>
        <PID.3>123</PID.3>    
        <PID.5>
            <PID.5.1>Name</PID.5.1>
            <PID.5.2>Firstname</PID.5.2>
        </PID.5>
        <PID.7>193106170000</PID.7>
        <PID.8>F</PID.8>
    </PID>
    <PV1>
        <PV1.2>E</PV1.2>            
    </PV1>
</HL7X>
```

Then you can get your Information from the String based XML or you parse it with any XMLDocument builder.

Comment: I see it handles the MSH segment incorrectly... MSH-1 should in fact be | while MSH-2 are the other reserved charaters.  This means all indices are off by one for the MSH segment.  That being said it does keep things simple which is quite nice, thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to parse messages in a generic way with HAPI though you may find yourself coding some extra and casting some of it's output as it was not designed to be used that way.

By this I mean that it is in fact supported, just that you will not have the benefits of many of HAPI's more advanced features.

With the use of the [Terser](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/xref/ca/uhn/hl7v2/examples/ExampleUseTerser.html), [Varies](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/base/apidocs/ca/uhn/hl7v2/model/Varies.html), [GenericComposite](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/base/apidocs/ca/uhn/hl7v2/model/GenericComposite.html) and [GenericPrimitives](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/base/apidocs/ca/uhn/hl7v2/model/GenericPrimitive.html) classes I was able to get a simple generic parser up and running in no time at all.  It's pretty basic mind you but it does what I need it to.

Next I want to have a look at the [MessageVisitor](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/base/apidocs/ca/uhn/hl7v2/model/MessageVisitors.html) see if I can't get some of the work done in a less hackish way (to read by not relying on casting as much).

Good luck, hope this helps